# Merge multiple input strings to sort alphabetically

Tags: string, sorting, merge

Help! Here I have a program, that sorts input strings alphabetically. The problem is that it sorts the entered strings seperately, but I need them merged and sorted together. What am i doing wrong?

```
  int main (void)
    {
       char repeat;
       do{
        char string[128], string1[128], temp;
        int n, i, j;
        cout<<"\nEnter symbols: "<<endl;
        gets(string);
        n = strlen(string);
        for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        {
            for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
            {
                int  s = tolower(string[i]) - tolower(string[j]);
                if ( s == 0 )
                {   
                    s = string[i] - string[j];
                }

                if (s > 0)
                {
                    temp = string[i];
                    string[i] = string[j];
                    string[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<"\nSorted alphabetically: "<<endl;
        printf("\n%s", string);
        printf("\n");

        cout<<"\nEnter more symbols: "<<endl;
        gets(string1);
        n = strlen(string1);
        for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        {
          for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
          {
            int  s = tolower(string1[i]) - tolower(string1[j]);
            if ( s == 0 )
            {   
             s = string1[i] - string1[j];
            }
            if (s > 0)
            {
              temp = string1[i];
              string1[i] = string1[j];
              string1[j] = temp;
            }
          }
        }
     cout<<"\nSorted alphabetically: "<<endl;
```

the function below merges the strings, when they both have been already sorted

```
  strcat(string, string1); 
  printf(\n%s", string);
  printf("\n");
  cout << "To repeat press j" << endl;
  cin >> repeat;
  }
  while ( repeat == 'j' );
  system("Pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to sort strings or chars?

Comment: chars - form the user input, so that after second input the new letters would merge with the old ones and then be sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to merge the strings into a new one.

```
int main (void)
    {
       char repeat;
       do{
        char string[128], string1[128],string2[256], temp;
        int n, i, j;
        cout<<"\nEnter symbols: "<<endl;
        gets(string);
        cout<<"\nEnter more symbols: "<<endl;
        gets(string1);
        strcpy (string2,string);
        strcat (string2,string1);
        // rest of your code here. You only need to sort string2
```